# Passing route parameter to ReactJS constructor results in TS7006

Tags: reactjs, constructor, react-router

I am having difficulties understanding how I can pass a route parameter to a ReactJS. I have the following code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import "isomorphic-fetch";

interface IFetchProject {
    project: IProject;
    loading: boolean;
}

export class Project extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, IFetchProject> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("this.props", this.props);
        let project: IProject = {} as IProject;
        this.state = {
            project: project, loading: true
        };
        fetch("api/Projects/"+ this.props.match.params.id)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<IProject>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ project: data, loading: false });
            });
    }
}
```

*(Some code omitted since the error occurs in this part)*

The compiler complains about `constructor(props)` with this error:
`TS7006 (TS) Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

The basic end goal is to have access to the route parameter in the constructor so I can use the parameter to get the correct data from my API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by replacing:

```
constructor(props) {
```

with

```
constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) {
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but it solved my problem.